# Pointwise convergence does not imply convergence of corresponding integrals

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to follow a counterexample of pointwise convergence implying the convergence of the corresponding integrals.

Suppose $\mathcal f_n$ is defined as follows on $\mathcal[0,1]$:

$\mathcal f_n$ :=

$\mathcal0$   if $\mathcal x=0$;

$\mathcal n$    if 0 $\lt$ $\mathcal x$ $\le$ $\frac {1}{n}$;

$\mathcal0$   if $\frac {1}{n}$ $\lt$ $\mathcal x$ $\le$ $\mathcal 1$

I understand how $\mathcal f_n$ converges pointwise to $\mathcal f(x)=0$ on $\mathcal [0,1]$.  However, I do not understand why the corresponding integrals are not.
The example says $\int(f_n(x) dx) = 1$ and $\int(f(x) dx) = 0$.  Why is this true?

Comment: Probably you mean  $f_n(x)=n$ vor $0<x\leq \frac1n$.

Answer (score 0):

You have
\begin{align*}
\int_0^1 f_n(x)\,dx = \int_0^{1/n}n\,dx = n\cdot\frac{1}{n} = 1,
\end{align*}
for each $n$. Hence
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_0^1 f_n(x)\,dx = \lim_{n\to\infty} 1 =  1.
$$
On the other hand, since $\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x) = 0$ for each $x$, we have
$$
\int_0^1\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)\,dx = \int_0^1 0\,dx = 0.
$$
So,
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_0^1 f_n(x)\,dx = 1 \ne 0 = \int_0^1\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)\,dx.
$$